# Voting system. What happened here?

Tags: discussion

Here we have two extremely similar questions, both by new users, both about almost exactly the same sentence, both extremely short, both not showing real research effort.

### Why do they have such a difference in votes?

[Question 1: Currently at (0 /-3): Difference between "unter" and "zwischen"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10167/difference-between-unter-and-zwischen)

[Question 2: Currently at (2 / 0): “From all of these boys” auf Deutsch? Dativ + Genitiv?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10197/from-all-of-these-boys-auf-deutsch-dativ-genitiv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not uncommon, that a question may arise from a previous question.

If we look closely at the second question we may see the difference because we are now being asked for the possibility of using genitive case but using the same example sentence. If they had used another example it would be an interesting and valid question (e.g. "In aller Munde" *vs.* "In allen Mündern"*).

From what we can see it appears that the questions were asked from different users. There is no indication for abuse of the voting system.